# mysql age wise counts based on constraint

Tags: mysql, group-by, mysql-workbench

i have a table as follows

| pid | patient_name | age | sex | dm | htn | ckd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | one | 10 | m | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | two | 15 | m | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | three | 30 | m | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 4 | four | 40 | f | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 5 | five | 50 | f | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 6 | six | 60 | f | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 7 | seven | 70 | m | 1 | 0 | 1 |

i need output counts as follows for male patients

| ranges | dm_count | htn_count | ckd_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 80+ | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 20-29 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 50-59 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| under 20 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 30-39 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 40-49 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 70-79 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 60-69 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

below i have mentioned the query i have used

```
select t.ranges, count(*) as occurences from (
                            select age,
                               case when age >= '0' and age < '20' then "under 20"
                               when age >= '20' and age < '30' then "20-29"
                               when age >= '30' and age < '40' then "30-39"
                               when age >= '40' and age < '50' then "40-49"
                               when age >= '50' and age < '60' then "50-59"
                               when age >= '60' and age < '70' then "60-69"
                               when age >= '70' and age < '80' then "70-79"
                               else "80+" end as ranges,sex
                               from patient_sample where sex='M') as t
                            group by t.ranges
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. No point selecting unused age and sex in the inner query; outer query does not use them

Comment: i need output counts as follows for male patients @CaiusJard

Comment: That is not a question

Comment: i need age wise counts (summed )for dm,htn and ckd fot the above table could you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your question is "how do I add the count columns for dm, htn and ckd?

Select them in the inner query and use SUM on them rather than COUNT in the outer query

```
select 
  t.ranges, 
  count(*) as occurences, 
  sum(htn) as htn_count 
  ...
from (
  select 
     htn,
     ...
     case when age >= '0' and age < '20' then "under 20"
```

Add the others in in the same pattern

Comment: No problem. To mark this question as answered, click the grey checkmark to the left of the answer so that it turns green. This changes the appearance of the question on the dashboard to let people know you're no longer seeking an answer

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I would probably do something like this...

```
 SELECT FLOOR(age/10)*10 range_start
      , SUM(dm) dm_count
      , SUM(htn) htn_count 
      , SUM(ckd) ckd_count 
   FROM datable 
  WHERE sex = 'm' 
  GROUP 
     BY FLOOR(age/10)*10;
+-------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
| range_start | dm_count | htn_count | ckd_count |
+-------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
|          10 |        2 |         1 |         2 |
|          30 |        1 |         0 |         1 |
|          70 |        1 |         0 |         1 |
+-------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
```

...and resolve any remaining aspects of the problem in application code